# Convergence of random variables series

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $\xi_1, ... \xi_n, ...$ - are independent random variables such that $\mathbb{P}(\xi_n=\pm 1/n)=1/2 $

I want to prove that if $\phi : \mathbb{N}  \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is any bijection of natural numbers, then the series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \xi_{\phi(n)}$ converges a.s.

In particular, that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \xi_n$ converges a.s

I think I can use Borel-Cantelli lemma, but I can't figure out how exactly. Please help.

Comment: thanks for editing

Comment: to use Borel-Cantelli, you first need a candidate for the limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy consequence of Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem. Note that $E\xi_{\phi (n)}=0$ for all $n$ and $E\xi^{2}_{\phi (n)}=\frac  1{\phi(n)^{2}}$. Sinec $\sum _n  \frac  1{\phi(n)^{2}} <\infty$  we get almost sure convergence of $\sum \xi_{\phi (n)}$.

[Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem

Take $A=1$ in this theorem].

Comment: oh, thank you very much!